# Clangformat for preprocessor directives

Tags: objective-c, clang, llvm, clang-format

Using [Clangformat](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html)

I currently have the following method:

```
- (void)myMethod    
{   
#if DEBUG  
    [ClassMethod enableLogging];
#endif
}
```

I wish for it to be displayed as so

```
- (void)myMethod
{
    #if DEBUG
    [ClassMethod enableLogging];
    #endif
}
```

Any ideas?

[LVVM Research Link](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17362)